# last iteration of forloop modify final output in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I m new to Vue so don't know how to solve this let me first show code then the problem, I m using Vue-Good-table

```
  methods:{

         getTotals(){
            var self = this;
            var new1=[];
            this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/purchases')
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log("response.data value")
              console.log(response.data)
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                   var item1=JSON.parse(response.data[i].pur_items);
                     console.log("item1 for index i time" +i)
                      console.log(item1)

                      new1=item1

                }
               console.log("final output")
               console.log(new1)


            })

        },

},
```

here is console log of for loop
[image]
now my problem is that instead of getting 5 array at final output (i.e at new1)
it always display 2 array i.e in last iteration it have 2 array that i was getting at final out any ideas what i m doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code, it is normal that in the end `new1` contains the array of the last iteration.

You should try replacing `new1 = item1;` with `new1 = new1.concat(item1);`

For more details on the methods of the `Array` prototype, I recommend taking a look at the [doc on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the array at each iteration, but you should concatenate them.

```js
methods: {

  getTotals() {
    var self = this;
    var new1 = [];
    this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/purchases')
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("response.data value")
        console.log(response.data)
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          var item1 = JSON.parse(response.data[i].pur_items);
          console.log("item1 for index i time" + i)
          console.log(item1)

          new1 = new1.concat(item1)

        }
        console.log("final output")
        console.log(new1)


      })

  },

},
```

Comment: Array.prototype.concat method doesn't modify array in place.

Comment: @bugs still same thing i m getting

Comment: Right, as erhesto pointed out, `concat` doesn't modify the array in place, but returns a new array. I've modified to answer to account for this